# How can I remove all instances of a string within a string inside a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
phraseSources.ToList().ForEach(i => i.JmdictMeaning ?? );
```

What I need to do, and I'm not it's possible using LINQ, is to remove all occurrences of a string looking like this:

```
[see=????????]
```

Note the ??? is meant to indicate there can be any amount of characters, except "]".

That appear inside of JmDictMeaning.   Note there might be one or more of these but they will always start with "[see=" and end with "]"

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Two things to be aware of: `ToList` will create a _copy_ of a source string list, and `ForEach` will _not_ modofy the list in-place. So you're "modifying" a copy of a copy of each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove all `[see=...]` patterns you can try `Regex.Replace`:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  // Add ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase" if required (if "See", "SEE" should be matched)
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[see=[^\]]*\]");

  // "abc[see=456]789" -> "abc789"
  var result = regex.Replace(source, "");
```

In your case:

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[see=[^\]]*\]"); 

  var list = phraseSources.ToList();

  list.ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));
```

Same idea if you want to filter out items with such strings:

```
  var result = phraseSources
    .Where(item => !regex.IsMatch(item.JmdictMeaning))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry,  I will leave mark your answer as correct in a while as leaving the question open will allow more people to see and upvote your very good answer.

Comment: @Alan2: It would be more polite for others if you mark the answer correct as soon as you're sure it's correct, so people can focus their energies helping other people with questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
phraseSources.ToList().RemoveAll(i => i == "xyz");
```

Yours I imagine would probably look something like

```
phraseSources.ToList().RemoveAll(i => i.StartsWith("[see=") && i.EndsWith("]"));
```

[Here's an example dotnetfiddle showing it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cfbUGm)

Comment: RemoveAll doesn't return the list, and `.ToList()` creates a copy, so this code will create a copy, modify that copy, and then throw that copy away.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove like this:

```
phraseSources.Select(ph => {ph.JmdictMeaning.Replace("[see=????????]", ""; return ph;})
    .ToList();
```

Let me show an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and query should look like this:

```
IList<Person> persons = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person(){FirstName = "one1[see=????????]", LastName = "LastName1" },
    new Person(){FirstName = "two1[see=????????]", LastName = "LastName1" },
    new Person(){FirstName = "three1", LastName = "LastName1" },
    new Person(){FirstName = "one[see=????????]", LastName = "LastName1" },
    new Person(){FirstName = "two", LastName = "LastName1" },
};

persons = persons.Select(p => { p.FirstName = p.FirstName.Replace("[see=????????]", ""); 
    return p; })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the ?? is just meant to indicate there can be any string there.